# Apache document root includes /var/www while serving pages

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I have Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I have multiple websites set-up using Vhost config files. They all serve as intended.

My problem is this, when I transferred my Magneto files, it serves them but formatting is off. Looking at source shows that all my CSS files are trying to pull from /`var/www/EXAMPLE/public_html` rather than just stopping at `public_html`.

basically instead of the path being `/var/www/EXAMPLE/public_html/dir/dir/cssfile.css`

It should be `/dir/dir/cssfile.css`

This is a brand new install of Ubuntu and all that is on it is Apache and PHP. I installed them via apt-get. I used vhost config files for each domain and all are identical minus the domain names and ip address's. This is on an unmanaged server on 1 and 1. I am transitioning from cPanel.

Here is a redacted example.com.conf for Apache

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@EXAMPLE.com
ServerName EXAMPLE.com
ServerAlias EXAMPLE.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/EXAMPLE.com/public_html/
    <Directory "/var/www/EXAMPLE.com/public_html/">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
                    Require all granted
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have spent hours trying to figure it out, I've tried userdir mod and many others. I am at a loss now.

EDIT:I have attempted a different server (XAMPP) on my localhost with my host file pointing to local host with these magento files. It worked as it did on the cPanel server. So I do not believe this to be a magento config problem, but a misconfiguration on my part with the server.

Comment: Did you check your Magento config as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778615/how-can-i-relocate-my-magento-stores-media-directory

Comment: The config for magento is stock, however this exact same set of files, works fine and does not have my problem as described above except for on this server that I setup myself. The tells me I did a misconfiguration on the server somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I was reading into my problem too much. It worked on XAMPP due to its less strict nature as that is more for development then anything else. on a "production" server, things are locked down alot more.

The problem was resolved by proper folder permissions and ownership. I am unsure why the folders in question caused it to react the way it did. Either way a few chmod commands and problem was fixed.